# ERROR Cannot start nuxt: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hook') in Nuxt v3.6.5

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, node-modules, upgrade

My project was working on Nuxt v2.15.8 but I have upgraded it to latest version (3.6.5).
I upgraded the node version to v20.3.1 as well.
When I run `npx nuxi dev`, it gives below error.

```
 ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hook')                            2:38:42 PM

  at nuxtBootstrapVue (node_modules\bootstrap-vue\nuxt\index.js:34:13)
  at installModule (.../node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:2409:101)
  at async initNuxt (/.../node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:3238:7)
  at async load (/.../node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:205:9)
  at async Object.invoke (/.../node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:249:5)
  at async _main (/.../node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:49:20)
```

What is solution without downgrading node version?
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.